# ToDo list на javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button id="button">Press</button>
    <div id="list"></div>
    <script>
(function name(){
    let input = this.input=document.getElementById('#input');
    let button = document.getElementById('#button');
    let str = this.str =document.getElementById('#str');
    if(input){
        button.addEventListener("onclick", add)
    }else{
        return fasle
    }
})
function add(){
    this.str +=this.input;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Судя по всему ошибка где-то в логике, но у меня просто не выводится строка в инпуте при нажатии на кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо того, что в функции `name` много ошибок, она еще и не вызывается.

```js
(function() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input');
  let button = document.getElementById('button');
  let str = document.getElementById('list');
  if (button)
    button.addEventListener("click", add);

  function add() {
    if (str && input) {
      var p = document.createElement('li');
      p.textContent = input.value;
      str.appendChild(p);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">Press</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Мне бы хотелось, чтоб это был как список, но когда я div исправляю на ul все остаются неизменным... Не подскажете, как это сделать?

Comment: @Just_Илья подсказал

Answer (score 1):

```js
    button.addEventListener('click', function () { // Слушаем нажатие кнопки id button
        name(); // Если нажата - вызываем функцию
    });

    function name(){
        let input = document.getElementById('input').value; // Получаем именно значение поля input
        let str = document.getElementById('l1'); // Получаес значение с классом l1, чтобы не создаватьлишний раз ul
        if(input){ // Если данные введены, то...
            add(str, input); // Вызываем функцию и передаём данные.
        }else{
            return false; // Если нет, то возвращаем false
        }
    }
    function add(str, input){
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = input;
        str.appendChild(li);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">Press</button>
<div id="list">
    <ul id="l1"></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```