# Вывод повторяющихся элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Дана строка кода:

```
let i = '********************'.split('').reduce((acc, val, ind) => [...acc, { id: ind > 10 ? 10 : ind }], [])
```

Из данного массива надо вывести все повторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: Вы забыли принять ответ на Ваш вопрос здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110992/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0  и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1102496/todo-list-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javascript.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск и подсчет одинаковых значений массива (js)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590571/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так "уникальные" или "повторяющиеся"?

```js
let all      = 'the walrus and the carpenter'.split('').sort();
let unique   = all.filter((el, i, a) => el != a[i+1] && el != a[i-1]);
let repeated = all.filter((el, i, a) => el == a[i+1] && el != a[i-1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(all));
console.log(JSON.stringify(unique));
console.log(JSON.stringify(repeated));
```

---

```js
let i = '********************'.split('').reduce((acc, val, ind) => [...acc, {
  id: ind > 10 ? 10 : ind
}], []);
let repeated = i.filter((el, i, a) => (a[i+1] && el.id == a[i+1].id) || (a[i-1] && el.id == a[i-1].id));
console.log(JSON.stringify(repeated));
```

Comment: Дико извиняюсь... Я имел ввиду повторяющиеся элементы массива; Ваш код выдает следующее: [{"id":0},{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10},{"id":10}], а требуется вывести элементы только с ключами "10", исходя из данной задачи.

Comment: let repeated = all.filter((el, i, a) => el == a[i+1] && el != 
a[i+1]);console.log(JSON.stringify(repeated)); В моем случае данный код вызывает пустой массив.